# Equivalent ORM query in Django of MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I am not well in django orm advance query.

***problem is:***

**select rows with max a column value distinct by other column and order by date (desc)**

I found answer on stackoverflow [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1)

**Answer in MYSQL is this (from above give url)**

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home) groupedtt 
ON tt.home = groupedtt.home 
AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Its Equivalent Django ORM query ..

My Model is

```
class ModelStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='---')
    fall = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
    rise = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    error_message = models.TextField(default=' ')
    to = models.ForeignKey('model1',
                           related_name="status",
                           related_query_name="hstatus")
```

distinct column: name

max value column: add_date

```
EXAMPLE

id  name  add_date     status   fall_count | rise_count
---|-----|------------|--------|-----------|--------
1  | ab  | 04/03/2009 | up     | 399       | 100
2  | aa  | 04/03/2009 | down   | 244       | 200
3  | aa  | 03/03/2009 | down   | 555       | 210
4  | ba  | 03/03/2009 | up     | 300       | 256
5  | ab  | 03/03/2009 | up     | 200       | 145


OUTPUT

id  name  add_date     status   fall_count | rise_count
---|-----|------------|--------|-----------|--------
1  | ab  | 04/03/2009 | up     | 399       | 100
2  | aa  | 04/03/2009 | down   | 244       | 200
4  | ba  | 03/03/2009 | up     | 300       | 256
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you at least show us your models, without that we have no hope of helping. And tell us in plain english what you want the query to return?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, model added  plz help

Comment: Still can't help, try and clearly explain what the output should look like.

Comment: try using [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, example added

Comment: So you want only the most recent rows from the table according to the name column?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, yes